# RoboCopy from Local Machine to Fileshare using Process.Start() throws access denied error

Tags: c#

I have network fileshare.The network share has login account where the user will be autheticated whenever they copy files to the directory.First of all user will create the directory in file share using `WindowsImpersonationContext` in c#.After creating directory user is coppying the file to the directory in the networkshare.

User is able to create directory in the network share but when the user starts robocopy by copying files from local machine to network file share, system says `Access denied`.I am using same user account for impersonating the to fileshare account while creating directory in the fileshare as well as robocopy.

please help me. please find the below code. 
is it possible to run robocopy as other account or impersonate other user account while copying file to network fileshare directory.

### create Directory in Network Fileshare

```
public void CreateFolder(string FilePath,string UserName,string DomainName,string Password)
   {
       try
       {

           string path = FilePath;
           bool impersonateResult=impersonateValidUser(UserName, DomainName, Password);
           if (impersonateResult)
           {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
           }

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           throw ex;  
       }
   }
```

### Impersonation while creating directory in Filshare

```
 public bool impersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
   {
       WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
       IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
       IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

       if (RevertToSelf())
       {
           if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
               LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
           {
               if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
               {
                   tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                   impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                   if (impersonationContext != null)
                   {
                       CloseHandle(token);
                       CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                       return true;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
           CloseHandle(token);
       if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
           CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
       return false;
   }
```

### Robocopy:

```
public void RoboCopy(string strSourceFilePath,string DestinationFilePath,string FileName,string UserName,String DomainName,string Password)
   {
       try
       {


           System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
           char[] pass = Password.ToCharArray();
           foreach (char c in pass)
            password.AppendChar(c);
            Process p = new Process();
           p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
           p.StartInfo.FileName = "Robocopy.exe";
           p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"  \"{1}\"  \"{2}\"  \"{3}\"   ", strSourceFilePath, DestinationFilePath, FileName,"/R:2" );
           p.StartInfo.Domain = DomainName;
           p.StartInfo.UserName = UserName;
           p.StartInfo.Password = password;       
           p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // set this to false so that we can redirect the output
           p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
           p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
           p.Start();
           string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           p.WaitForExit();



       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // Setting the Error Description in CommonFunctions Class.
             throw ex; 
       }
   }
```

While doing robocopy only I am getting access denied error when I copy file from local machine to Network Filesahre using Fileshare Login account.
I am able to create directory without any access denied error?

Comment: Does the user (you are running robocopy under) have enough permissions to access the files on the local machine?

Comment: I have added that user account in my local pc with full permission.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar (not using RoboCopy though) and what worked for me was mapping a drive on your source machine to the remote machine using the username and password that has the required permissions.  Once the drive is mapped, you can copy files, create directories, etc.  Below is some code that will handle the mapping:

```
public class DriveSettings
{
    private enum ResourceScope
    {
        RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 1,
        RESOURCE_GLOBALNET,
        RESOURCE_REMEMBERED,
        RESOURCE_RECENT,
        RESOURCE_CONTEXT
    }
    private enum ResourceType
    {
        RESOURCETYPE_ANY,
        RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
        RESOURCETYPE_PRINT,
        RESOURCETYPE_RESERVED
    }
    private enum ResourceUsage
    {
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_NOLOCALDEVICE = 0x00000004,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_SIBLING = 0x00000008,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED = 0x00000010
    }
    private enum ResourceDisplayType
    {
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NETWORK,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_ROOT,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHAREADMIN,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DIRECTORY,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_TREE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NDSCONTAINER
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct NETRESOURCE
    {
        public ResourceScope oResourceScope;
        public ResourceType oResourceType;
        public ResourceDisplayType oDisplayType;
        public ResourceUsage oResourceUsage;
        public string sLocalName;
        public string sRemoteName;
        public string sComments;
        public string sProvider;
    }
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2
        (ref NETRESOURCE oNetworkResource, string sPassword,
        string sUserName, int iFlags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2
        (string sLocalName, uint iFlags, int iForce);

    public static void MapNetworkDrive(string sDriveLetter, string sNetworkPath, string userName, string password)
    {
        //Checks if the last character is \ as this causes error on mapping a drive.
        if (sNetworkPath.Substring(sNetworkPath.Length - 1, 1) == @"\")
        {
            sNetworkPath = sNetworkPath.Substring(0, sNetworkPath.Length - 1);
        }

        NETRESOURCE oNetworkResource = new NETRESOURCE();
        oNetworkResource.oResourceType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
        oNetworkResource.sLocalName = sDriveLetter + ":";
        oNetworkResource.sRemoteName = sNetworkPath;

        //If Drive is already mapped disconnect the current 
        //mapping before adding the new mapping
        if (IsDriveMapped(sDriveLetter))
        {
            DisconnectNetworkDrive(sDriveLetter, true);
        }

        WNetAddConnection2(ref oNetworkResource, password, userName, 0);
    }

    public static int DisconnectNetworkDrive(string sDriveLetter, bool bForceDisconnect)
    {
        if (bForceDisconnect)
        {
            return WNetCancelConnection2(sDriveLetter + ":", 0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return WNetCancelConnection2(sDriveLetter + ":", 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsDriveMapped(string sDriveLetter)
    {
        string[] DriveList = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
        for (int i = 0; i < DriveList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sDriveLetter + ":\\" == DriveList[i].ToString())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it for example like this:

```
if (!DriveSettings.IsDriveMapped(mapDriveLetter)) // For example: "K"
{
    DriveSettings.MapNetworkDrive(mapDriveLetter, shareName, adminUserName, adminPassword);
}
```

And after the copying, disconnect it:

```
if (DriveSettings.IsDriveMapped(mapDriveLetter))
{
    DriveSettings.DisconnectNetworkDrive(mapDriveLetter, true);
}
```